# C# click button in form without knowing the ID or any strong identifier?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I am trying to click a form submit button, I have been able to fill in the form fields but I am struggling to fire the submit button because of the lack of things I can use to identify it?

Instagram:

```
<button class="_ah57t _84y62 _i46jh _rmr7s">Sign up</button>
```

How can I click the button, without having the ID or any strong identifier that wont be mixed up?

How I do the input fields

```
private void FindAndFillElement(string tag, string attribute, string attributeValue, string attributeReplace, string attributeReplaceValue)
{
    foreach (HtmlElement elem in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName(tag))
    {
        if (elem.GetAttribute(attribute) == attributeValue)
        {
            elem.SetAttribute(attributeReplace, attributeReplaceValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Calling:

```
FindAndFillElement("input", "name", "emailOrPhone", "value", "some-email@mail.com");
```

Comment: You can target based on the buttons position in the DOM. Is the button always going to exist at the same location? That is to say, is there always going to be the same amount of content preceding it? If you, if you could post your rendered HTML please.

Comment: It's the HTML on Instagram, its available for anyone to look at, although I am looking at it from Inspect Element not view source.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the button, just call the form submit function

```
document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
```

Comment: This is a bad answer because the form doesn't have an ID to hook onto.

Comment: This is a bad comment as you missed the point entirely which is to show you that once you have the element then you can just call submit. You can get an element by id, tag name, class name, css selectors, object collections. Add jQuery in the mix then you have even more options and systematic ways to get the form element.

Comment: But the form element didn't have any unique identifiers, even the classes have been repeated at least once in the web page.

Comment: It doesn't matter. How many form elements are on that entire page? 1. There is one form element. You have the option to use a queryselector to get it. If you have ANY inputs inside the form then you can find the closets element of type form. You can use getElementsByTagName. There are multiple ways. Interesting that you are trying to force hack the UI though with a perfectly good API they serve ready to use.....

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering, I answered it using this.

```
private void ClickButtonByInnerText(string innerText)
{
    foreach (HtmlElement elem in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button"))
    {
        if (elem.InnerText == innerText)
        {
            elem.InvokeMember("Click");
        }
    }
}
```